# Inner html tags keep showing up inside of quotes after jQuery prepend

Tags: jquery, html, dom, iframe

I'm trying to prepend a part a noscript tag with an iframe child tag into the body.  I'm using jQuery.  While the prepend does work, what I'm seeing is that the iframe tag is always showing up inside of quotes.  If I prepend the noscript first and then prepend the iframe within the noscript, that works fine. Not sure why it's doing that, if someone can explain, that'd be terrific!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').prepend('<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-123ABC" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>');
});
```

Result:

```
<noscript>
"<iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-123ABC" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>"
</noscript>
```

Comment: Haha what? Use JavaScript to append noscript tag? :D

Comment: noscript tag should written by HTML or server side like PHP.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are testing it with JavaScript enabled, Chrome quotes the innerHTML of the noscript tag, making it plain text. Second, if you disable JavaScript, jQuery won't work, failing to do what you want (adding an alternative to JavaScript)
You must add it without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of 'noscript' tag is not correct. The  tag defines an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn't support script.

```
<script>
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Refer this link: 
http://www.ghacks.net/2014/11/29/how-to-use-noscript-efficiently/